# Connecting NodeJS Express to MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database, node.js, sql-server-2008, sequelize.js

I'm a NodeJS newbie and I am building an application that talks to an MSSQL (SQL Server 2008 R2) Database. For this, I tried using [Sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/getting-started/), an ORM library that claims to do so.
While I have been successful in making it work with MySQL, SQL Server connection is just not working. I connected to a local database on both the occasions. Here's what I tried (as given in the docs):

[Part 1: Establish Connection]

```
... Express Code ...
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');

var sequelize = new Sequelize('NewDB', '', '', {
  host: '(localdb)\v11.0',
  dialect: 'mssql',

  pool: {
    max: 5,
    min: 0,
    idle: 10000
  }
});
```

[Part 2: Testing]

```
var User = sequelize.define('user', {
  firstName: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    field: 'first_name' // Will result in an attribute that is firstName when user facing but first_name in the database
  },
  lastName: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING
  }
}, {
  freezeTableName: true // Model tableName will be the same as the model name
});

User.sync({force: true}).then(function () {
  // Table created
  return User.create({
    firstName: 'John',
    lastName: 'Hancock'
  });
});

... Express Code ...
```

The database NewDB does exist on the server. Now, While using SQL Server Express, the same credentials work. But not here. The error that I see is:

> Unhandled rejection SequelizeConnectionError: Failed to connect to (localdb)\v11.0:1433 = getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND (localdb)\v11.0

So, here's the question. What credentials do I put, so that it works? And if it doesn't what would be alternate library to establish a Database connection? I'll prefer an ORM, but it's not that important a thing (anything works as long as I can connect to the DB).

Comment: Sequelize uses the [tedious](http://pekim.github.io/tedious/api-connection.html) library to connect to mssql. Try to connect with tedious first  and see if that works

Comment: @JanAagaardMeier Nope, not working with vanilla tedious too.

Comment: Perhaps tedious does not support that way of specifying the host then? And if tedious does not support it, neither does sequelize I'm afraid. Perhaps try with [node-mssql](https://github.com/patriksimek/node-mssql) instead. It has bindings for tedious, and the native windows connector maintained by microsoft, msnodesql(https://www.npmjs.com/package/msnodesql)

Comment: @JanAagaardMeier you're probably right. It did work when I connected to a remote SQL server. Let me wait if someone does have a solution wherein I can connect to a local DB.

Comment: I'm trying out different node modules and I know for a fact that tedious works because it's worked with the other modules. However, I'm having similar problems to you with sequelize. I'll post an answer if I figure it out.